# From inside of a Docker container, how can I use selenium and webdriver to access the localhost server running at http://127.0.0.1:8090/?

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing selenium python tests on a docker image. 
Currently I have a server running on localhost using url http://127.0.0.1:8090/ How can I use selenium to access my localhost chrome browser. This is the code I have written, however it is not connecting my docker image to my localhost.

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"/exabgp/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8090/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//{*0id="sss0"}/li/{19}/a***).click()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 0):

You can use solutions mentioned in [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Or

When you run your container use `--add-host`

```
docker run --add-host `myapp:<IPOfyourAppServer>` ....
```

And then in your code use

```
driver.get("http://myapp:8090/")
```

**Edit-1**

If you are using `docker-compose`, you need to use `extra_hosts` options

```
services:
  myapp:
    extra_hosts:
      - "myapp:192.168.0.10"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. The problem I have is that my infrastructure uses docker-compose so I'm not sure how to link my docker-compose to run --add-host `myapp:<IPOfyourAppServer>` ....

Comment: @MaxCopley, if this works for you, can accept this as an answer?

Comment: Hi Tarun, the fix to the solution was running docker containers in non sandbox mode and also setting the privileged mode boolean to true. Thank you for the suggestion Tarun.

Comment: What did you use for non sandbox mode?

Comment: @MaxCopley Do you mind extending your answer above? I have a similar issue.